# Database display output using data bindings in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, database, xaml, database-connection

I'm having major issues with Data Binding in my XAML code.

What I'm trying to do is get a database view, populated by binding. Although for all I can do, it is not working.

So in my `DatabaseView.xaml` I have the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=patView}" />
```

So from what I can see, I want `patView` to connect to the method `patView` In the `DatabaseView.xaml.cs` file as such

```
public string sqlStatement = Queries.SelectAll;

public DataView patView     
{
        get
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = DataBaseConnection.GetDataSet(sqlStatement);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            return dt.DefaultView;
        }

    }
```

For completeness, `SelectAll` is in the `Queries.cs` file which contains

```
public static string SelectAll = "SELECT * FROM PatData";
```

I'm really struggling with getting the database to actaully populate using this binding method, and any help is massivley appreciated. I will edit this with any more code that you need to know :)

Comment: Do you get any output errors?

Comment: None at all. But the `PatientView` method has 0 reference on it, and if I put a break point, it is never reached

Comment: If it does not call it then it does not see it, therefore there should be an output error 40: saying that it could not find patView.

Comment: All I have is using resharper, it says Cannot resolve symbol patView due to unknown DataContext

Comment: have you set the dataContext ?

Comment: Hmm I had back before I changed around my code, and now it's all gone. Where abouts should I set the data content?

Comment: If you have not set it, then you must have an output error in the output window. From the code behind in user control/window you just say DataContext = new YourViewModel (there are many ways of doing it). It would be better if you post more code and xaml so everybody can see what you're actually doing.

Comment: I've done some tweaking to try and get the DataContext in, but now I have a stockoverflowexpection on InitialiseComponent of my ViewModel

Comment: Guys, I have fixed most of my errors, and have now reverted to an old list style, can you help me boost up to database? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924821/converting-from-normal-list-data-to-a-database-in-wpf-xaml